# A method to find the mode numbers

Tags: java, arrays, mode

I have wrote a method to find the mode number of an array, length of the array is 10 so i have ten numbers in the array so the size is full . My question is if the mode is more than one number how i modify my code to display both numbers !

Ex if my array looks like this `[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,5,6,8]` the mode in this case is 1 and 2 . in my code it only prints the first mode it gets.
so it will print mode is 1.

```
public static int arryMode (int [] randomList) {
    int maxValue = 0;
    int maxCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < randomList.length; ++i) {
        int count = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < randomList.length; ++j) {
             if (randomList[j] == randomList[i]) {
                 ++count;
             }
        }

        if (count > maxCount) {
            maxCount = count;
            maxValue = randomList[i];
        }
    }

    return maxValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to collect the several max values, and instead of replacing the maxValue when a greater max for count is found, you need to start with new max values. An extra case is needed for all those equal to the max value.

To not add a max value repeatedly look whether a new randomList[i] already is in the max values, and/or use a Set.

```
public static Set<Integer> arryMode(int[] randomList) {
    Set<Integer> maxValues = new LinkedHashSet<>(10);
    int maxCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < randomList.length; ++i) {

        if (maxValues.contains(randomList[i])) { // Heuristic.
            continue;
        }

        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < randomList.length; ++j) {
            if (randomList[j] == randomList[i]) {
                ++count;
            }
        }
        if (count > maxCount) {
            maxCount = count;
            maxValues.clear();
            maxValues.add(randomList[i]);
        } else if (count == maxCount) {
            maxValues.add(randomList[i]);
        }
    }
    return maxValues;
}
```

With

```
for (int maxValue : maxValues) { ... }
```

Comment: i tried to work with this code , but i got compiler error says the the required is Set<integer> found int thx anyway

Comment: sorry its the other way round

Answer (score 0):

You would use an `ArrayList<Integer>` to store all the values of the mode. An ArrayList is an object behaving as a resizable array. Each time you would find a new mode, if its count is equald to the previous max count, then you would add it to the list. If the count is bigger than the previous max count, then you would clear the list, and add the new mode to the list.

Read the [Java tutorial on collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/).